# How to access data returned as python dictionary from Mint Scraper - mintapi by mrooney

Tags: python, dictionary, screen-scraping, linux-mint

The Mint Scraper I am referring to is mintapi by mrooney found on github https://github.com/mrooney/mintapi

When I call mint.get_budgets() how do I access specifics amounts spent?

For example how would I display how much I spent on "Food & Dining"

```
    #get budget data as json
    response = json.loads(.....)

    # Make the skeleton return structure
    budgets = {
        'income': response['data']['income'][
            str(max(map(int, response['data']['income'].keys())))
        ]['bu'],
        'spend': response['data']['spending'][
            str(max(map(int, response['data']['income'].keys())))
        ]['bu']
    }

    # Fill in the return structure
    for direction in budgets.keys():
        for budget in budgets[direction]:
            budget['cat'] = categories[budget['cat']]

    return budgets
```

[Here](https://github.com/mrooney/mintapi/blob/master/mintapi/api.py#L266-L299) is the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to access specific spending amounts by category

to access amount spent

```
    print(budget['spend'][0]['amt'])
```

to access the category:

```
    print(budget['spend'][0]['cat']['parent']['name'])
```

Explanation:

.get_budgets() returns a dictionary with two key:value pairs, Income & Spending

the key "Spending:" contains a list of dictionaries each dictionary contains a spending subcategory e.g. "Food & Dining: Groceries"